# Require.JS ignoring min in filename

Tags: javascript, requirejs

i try load some files with ".min" in the filename, but the RequireJS try load this files without min.

Example:

```
<script data-main="//assets/js/main" src="//assets/js/require.js"></script>


require(["jquery-1.10.2.min", "jquery.ui.widget", "tmpl.min", "load-image.min"], function( $ ) {
    console.log( $ ) // OK
});
```

The console show:

```
Cannot load "http://myurl.com/assets/js/load-image.js" (404)
```

Comment: Do you pass a configuration to RequireJS?

Comment: Not, i don't setting anything.